# How do I convert a 2x2 contingency table into a long format dataframe?

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr, splitstackshape

How do I convert a 2x2 contingency table into a long format data frame?
I tried this:

```
library(reshape2)
Table <- matrix(c(7,67,19,71), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(Table) <- c('Drug', 'No_Drug')
colnames(Table) <- c('Comp', 'No_Comp')
melt(Table)
```

I get this rather than a data frame of 164 rows categorized by Drug vs. No_Drug

```
  Var1    Var2 value
1    Drug    Comp     7
2 No_Drug    Comp    19
3    Drug No_Comp    67
4 No_Drug No_Comp    71
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `data.frame(expand.grid(rownames(Table), colnames(Table)), value = c(Table))`?

Comment: All these tags and no `r` tag <sigh>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to convert your 4x3 molten data.frame into a 164x2 data.frame. You could try `expandRows()` from the `splitstackshape` package:

> Expands (replicates) the rows of a data.frame or a data.table, either
>   by a fixed number, a specified vector, or a value contained in one of
>   the columns in the source data.frame or a data.table.

In your case, simply do:

```
library(splitstackshape)
m <- melt(Table)
expandRows(m, "value")
```

**Note:** This is a convenient wrapper around base R:

```
out <- m[rep(sequence(nrow(m)), m[["value"]]), ]
out[["value"]] <- NULL
```

Comment: I suggest that the moderators add a tag for the package splitstackshape

Comment: @FTF I added the tag. If you ever happen to have a question related to this package, you'll be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Steven Beaupré.
Might not 
    library(dplyr) 
    filter(out) ##work too?

Comment: It would be `dplyr::select(out, -value)`